# Open source iSightCapture?

Tags: command-line, webcam, open-source

Is there an open source program like [iSightCapture](http://www.applausible.com/blog/?p=144)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3rd link in Google: http://rondam.blogspot.com/2008/07/isightcapture-secrets-revealed.html

> For anyone who has used iSightCapture and has been frustrated by the fact that it's released in object-code only format, here is [qt-capture](http://www.flownet.com/ron/code/qt-capture.m) which is not quite as capable as iSightCapture (it doesn't have any command-line arguments) but does basically the same thing. Since it's just a proof-of-concept and not really finished code I've released it into the public domain.